# Error in building service in liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay

I am new to liferay and making a sample application for database operations.  But I end up getting errors while building services. The stack trace is as follows:-

```
1. ERROR in E:\Liferay 6.2 CE GA-3\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\portletsessiondemo-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\sample\model\userdetails.java (at line 1)
    [javac]     /**
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2. ERROR in E:\Liferay 6.2 CE GA-3\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\portletsessiondemo-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\sample\service\ClpSerializer.java (at line 0)
    [javac]     /**
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2 problems (2 errors)

BUILD FAILED
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.. I downgraded the jdk version from 1.8 to 1.7 and the problem is solved. Seems like service builders are not compatible with 1.8